# Create JavaScript variable name from another variable

Tags: javascript, variables, object, reference

I have this object

```
function paymentPlan(name, price, days, active){
        this.name=name;
        this.price=price;
        this.days=days;
        this.active=active;
    }

    var plan_1 = new paymentPlan("unlimited", 0, -1, -1);
    var plan_2 = new paymentPlan("starter", 100, 7, 2);
```

and I need to select one of the object instances by building the variable instance from another variable, essentially add the number to the end of the reference

for example If i needed to print out the name of plan_2 when selected, I need to build the reference like so

```
var plan_id = 2;

alert( plan_+plan_id.name );
```

how can I do that?

Comment: ? plan_id and plan_ are not in the object/code above, can you clarify your meaning?

Comment: Why not use an array instead, where the index is the plan id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your variables globally, then you may use `window` object:

```
window["plan_" + plan_id].name;
```

However, you may always initialise the variables inside a locally defined object, e.g.:

```
var plans = {
    plan_1 : new paymentPlan("unlimited", 0, -1, -1),
    plan_2 : new paymentPlan("starter", 100, 7, 2)
};

plans["plan_" + plan_id].name;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your best approach would be to store the plans in an `array`.

```
var plans = [];
plans.push(new paymentPlan("unlimited", 0, -1, -1));
plans.push(new paymentPlan("starter", 100, 7, 2));

var plan_id = 1;
alert(plans[plan_id].name); // "starter"
```

Comment: oh yea!! why didn't I use an array, I'll use an array instead. Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: @Aesthete, you might like to change `plan_id = 2` to `plan_id = 1` because `plans[2]` doesn't exist in your example as it stands.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - Indeed! Good spot. Fixed.

Comment: Well my example is a little different then what's in the code, I'm using PHP to spit out the javascript instances, and the number at the end of "plan_" is the id number of the plan in the database, and I needed to call that plan by it's ID number, so I don't even need "plan_" I can just use plan[2] instead. I made a bad choice for choosing an object. Also I was under the impression that you could only select one answer on stack overflow, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parent object

```
var plans = {};
var plan_1 = new paymentPlan("unlimited", 0, -1, -1);
plans["plan_1"] = plan_1;
alert( plans["plan_"+plan_id.name] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `eval()`.

```
alert(eval('plan_'+plan_id+'.name'));
```

Comment: @MattiMehtonen, this is stereotype, if you sanitize data and 100% sure about what you are doing this is very  handy tool. BW look at jQuery 'globalEval' they are using it ;)

Comment: @dmi3y. Ok then. (eval == evil) :)

Comment: This answer is the closest to what the OP asked for (although the other methods accomplish the same result). You could wrap it in `if(!isNaN(plan_id)){}` for safety.